# How to convert component string as real component in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi i have a requirement for plugin store where i need to load component from core into plugins and inside plugin i need to convert that string into real component so that i can use it.

**Note:** better approach is most welcome in the view of plugin store inside core

**my pseudo logic**

1. get component from specified path through `http`
2. convert loaded string into real vue component and store it in a variable
3. render it in dom

```js
let componentAsString = 

`<template>
  <div>
      <h class="red">{{title}}</h>
      <!--<A></A> -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
//import A from './components/A'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data(){
      return {
        title:'Hello World'
      }
  },
  /*components: {
    A
  }*/
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
   .red{color:red;}
</style>`;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
  
  
  <div id="app">

  </div>
```

Comment: Maybe look into Async Components (https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-dynamic-async.html#async-components)

Comment: I'm not sure if a component with `data` can work properly that way. If you can transfer component as a JavaScript object, it would be much easier.

Comment: @JakobE, i don't see any `http` call in `defineAsyncComponent` there are only imports

Comment: Dynamic import supports http url: `const myComp = defineAsyncComponent(() =>
  import('http://mywebsite.com/components/my-comp.vue')
)`

Answer (score 2):

You have chosen very difficult approach to solve the requirement. Main problem is the content of the string - it is essentially a Vue [SFC](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) (`.vue` file). In order to turn this SFC into a Vue component usable in the browser a lot must be done. You must use Webpack (or Rollup or any other bundler), use [vue-loader](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/) inside to parse the SFC and use different Webpack loaders to process each section of SFC (Babel to transpile the `<scipt>` block, sass-loader and sass compiler to turn `<style lang="scss">` into CSS)

There are tools for doing most of this (with limitations) in the browser like for example [vue3-sfc-loader](https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/vue3-sfc-loader) but the cost is huge - vue3-sfc-loader weights around [1.4MB of minified javascript](https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/vue3-sfc-loader#dist) (add Vue itself or potential CSS preprocessor on top of that) and I bet performance of such solution will not be great either

Much easier approach is to use this standard tooling at **build time**

1. Just create your components as you normally do - in `.vue` files
2. Use your components as [Async Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components) and build a "dictionary" of available components. Those components will be build at build time into separate js files and loaded into a browser on demand (when used)

```js
// ComponentStore.js
export default {
  component1: () => import('./components/component1'),
  component2: () => import('./components/component2'),
}
```

*Note: process of creating this dictionary can be automated too ([inspiration](https://github.com/bencodezen/vue-enterprise-boilerplate/blob/main/src/state/modules/index.js))*

3. Use the component as [dynamic component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components)

```js
// DynamicComponent.vue
<template>
  <component :is="comp" />
</template>
<script>
import ComponentStore from "ComponentStore.js"

export default {
  props: ['componentName'],
  computed: {
    comp() {
      return ComponentStore[this.componentName]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```